# Vue 3 - How do I force render a dynamic component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How do I force render a dynamic component?

In this case only the last tab's component mounts.  I want them all to mount once.

```
const addTab = (symbol: string) => {
  const id = nextTabId++;
  tabs.value.push({
    id,
    symbol,
    component: markRaw(ChartComponent),
  });
  activeTabId.value = id;
};

onMounted(() => {
  addTab("USD");
  addTab("EUR");
});

  <KeepAlive>
    <component
      :key="activeTab?.id"
      :is="activeTab?.component"
    />
  </KeepAlive>
```

Comment: a dynamic component is only ever a **single** component.  The dynamic part is that it can become a different component based on some condition that you set.  If you want **multiple** components to render, you need to add multiple components to your template.  You can add them manually or render them in a [v-for loop](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#v-for-with-a-component)

Comment: It's unclear how it's supposed to work exactly. The last tab mounts because you set it in activeTab. Another one will be rendered once activeTab is changed. There may be no need to keep multiple tab instances simultaneously because only one of them is shown. In case you need to do this for some reason you'd need to use a loop as it's suggested, but the necessity is not obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not using `KeepAlive` and use `v-show`

```
<div v-for="tab in tabs" :key="tab.id">
  <component :is="tab.component" v-show="activeTabId === tab.id"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a tab, only one content component is needed at once. I've tried a simple solution. Hope this helps.

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { onMounted, ref, reactive } from 'vue';
import ChartComponent from './ChartComponent.vue';
interface Tab {id: number, symbol: string}
const tabs: Tab[] = reactive([]);
let nextTabId = 0
const activeTabId = ref(0)

const addTab = (symbol: string) => {
  const id = nextTabId++;
  tabs.push({
    id,
    symbol,
  });
};

onMounted(() => {
  addTab("USD");
  addTab("EUR");
});
</script>
<template>
<div class="tabs" v-if="tabs.length">
  <button v-for="tab in tabs" :key="tab.id"
    @click="activeTabId = tab.id"
  >
    {{tab.id}} - {{ tab.symbol }}
  </button>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
  <component :is="ChartComponent" :symbol="tabs[activeTabId].symbol"/>
</div>
</template>
```

**Note:**
If different components for different tab items are required, then they can be put into the tabs array with a new component property, which should trigger no issue. Dynamic props can be fed using `v-bind` attribute in the component.

[Demo](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: I have a req that each tab run its mount method.

Comment: It does, checkout the demo, when you click the tab buttons, each tab should be loaded with it's own content.

Comment: :key is necessary, otherwise it's not remounted

Comment: Checked again and no the mount method is not called on each component, only the last one.